# In GWT, why shouldn't a method return an interface?

Tags: gwt

In [this video from Google IO 2009](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html), the presenter very quickly says that signatures of methods should return concrete types instead of interfaces.

From what I heard in the video, this has something to do with the GWT Java-to-Javascript compiler.

- What's the reason behind this choice ?
- What does the interface in the method signature do to the compiler ?
- What methods can return interfaces instead of concrete types, and which are better off returning concrete instances ?

[image: Snippet of code from Google IO presentation showing it's better that your method returns ArrayList than List]

Comment: It has to do with RPC serialization. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059787/gwt-using-listserializable-in-a-rpc-call

Comment: Look at or just after the 7 minute point in the presentation.  The speaker doesn't know exactly why he is doing it.  He calls it 'superstition'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has to do with the gwt-compiler, as you say correctly. **EDIT: However, as Daniel noted in a comment below, this does not apply to the gwt-compiler in general but only when using GWT-RPC.**

If you declare List instead of ArrayList as the return type, the gwt-compiler will include the complete List-hierarchy (i.e. all types implementing List) in your compiled code. If you use ArrayList, the compiler will only need to include the ArrayList hierarchy (i.e. all types implementing ArrayList -- which usually is just ArrayList itself). Using an interface instead of a concrete class you will pay a penalty in terms of compile time and in the size of your generated code (and thus the amount of code each user has to download when running your app).

You were also asking for the reason: If you use the interface (instead of a concrete class) the compiler does not know at compile time which implementations of these interfaces are going to be used. Thus, it includes all possible implementations.

Regarding your last question: all methods CAN be declared to return interface (that is what you ment, right?). However, the above penalty applies.

And by the way: As I understand it, this problem is not restricted to methods. It applies to all type declarations: variables, parameters. Whenever you use an interface to declare something, the compiler will include the complete hierarchy of sub-interfaces and implementing classes. (So obviously if you declare your own interface with only one or two implementing classes then you are not incurring a big penalty. That is how I use interfaces in GWT.)

In short: use concrete classes whenever possible.

(Small suggestion: it would help if you gave the time stamp when you refer to a video.)

Comment: the code bloat is only for classes used with code generation (e.g. GWT-RPC). In general the compiler does NOT bloat when using interfaces

Comment: **Daniel, you are right!** I totally forgot that one might use GWT without GWT-RPC.

Comment: @danielkurka - Do you know if this GWT-RPC interface bloat is still an issue in more recent versions of GWT?

Comment: Is this still true for 2.8.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

This and other performance tips were presented at Google IO 2011 - [High-performance GWT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F5zc1UAt2Y).

At about the 7 min point the speak addresses 'RPC Type Explosion':
[image: #4 Watch out for RPC type explosion]

For some reason I thought the GWT compiler would optimize it away again but it appears I was mistaken.

Comment: Is this still true for 2.8.0 ?